A complete metric space with midpoints is a length space
Let $X$ be a complete metric space and suppose that for all $x,y\in X$ there exists a midpoint $z\in X$ such that $$\frac{1}{2}d(x,y)=d(x,z)=d(y,z)$$
To show that this complete metric space is a length space, one constructs a map on $\sigma:S\rightarrow X$ (where $S$ is the set of dyadic rationals in $[0,1]$) in the following way: set $\sigma(0)=x$ and $\sigma(1)=y$. And then define $\sigma(1/2)$ to be the midpoint of $x$ and $y$ and then $\sigma(1/4)$ to be the midpoint of $\sigma(1/2)$ and $\sigma(0)$ and so on. Using completeness of $X$ one then extends it to a curve $[0,1]\rightarrow X$ to obtain a curve of minimal length.
But every time I see this proof, the fact the constructed map $S\rightarrow X$ is $d(x,y)$-Lipschitz is glossed over and it's not obvious to me why that's true.
I don't have an issue after knowing that it's Lipschitz.

$d(S(k/2^n), S((k+1)/2^n)) = 2^{-n} d(x,y)$ for $0 \le k \le 2^n-1$ by induction,
and then $d(S(a),S(b)) \le |a-b| d(x,y))$ by triangle inequality.

Should it be $\frac{1}{2^n}$ in the first line?
